# How can I add a control to my master page and validate it before the normal page submit events happen?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I would like to add a control to a master page (that will go on almost all the pages in my site). In it I am going to add a custom user control. I would like to be able to have it such that when the user hits the normal submit button the page the control on the master page is validated first and only if it is ok the rest of the normal process takes place. I am looking to do this with a minimal amount of changes to each page. I currently have a custom "Page" class I am using on each webpage that inherits the normal Page class so I can make changes to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Page.Validate method to explicitly validate your page and check Page.IsValid property to see if page is valid. 
If Page.IsValid is false the don't execute your code.

If you are not setting ValidationGroup for your submit control, I think the Validation on user control should fire by default.

Comment: yea, this is what I've been going with so far. It isn't perfect because I still need to edit each individual page in multiple places but it could definitely be worse.

Comment: I don't see any other way. But you can call Page.Validate in your BasePage Load but perform Page.IsValid check in your Control's postback handler e.g. Button click.